# Method references with a parameter

Tags: java, lambda

In Java 8, with the following class

```
 class Person {

    private boolean born;

    Person() {
    }

    public void setBornTrue() {
        born = true;
    }

    public void setBorn(boolean state) {
        born = state;
    }

  }
```

it is possible to call the setBornTrue method via a method reference:

```
    ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    people.add(new Person());

    people.forEach(Person::setBornTrue);
```

but how would I use the forEach method and use the setBorn using a **method reference**? Trying:

```
    people.forEach(Person::setBorn);
```

results in an error, "Cannot resolve method setBorn".

In addition, how would I pass in the value of True?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? This is wrong - `people.add(new Person(null));people.forEach(Person::setBornTrue);`

Comment: `people.add(new Person(null));` is this line right ? why null ?  your code works for me but if you removed `null`.

Comment: Cut and paste error ... removed the null.

Comment: I am wondering why this is not possible as well.

Comment: Take a look at MethodHandle, but it so complicated, nothing like std::bind in C++

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With lambda:

```
people.forEach((p) -> p.setBorn(true));
```

Found no other ways only using the java 8 API.

---

With this custom function:

```
public static <T, U> Consumer<T> bind2(BiConsumer<? super T, U> c, U arg2) {
    return (arg1) -> c.accept(arg1, arg2);
}
```

You can do:

```
people.forEach(bind2(Person::setBorn, true));
```

If this kind of utility methods is available in the java API or in a library, please let us know.

Comment: Yes ... while the answer above is how to set this *without* a method reference, is there no way to code this *with* a method reference?

Comment: @user465342 Updated with an alternative solution, which is not plain java, but uses a method reference.

Comment: Very impressive! Is there any reference you used to create that? Been looking for a good resource.