# Use method reference with parameter

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, method-reference, functional-interface

I just started learning Java streams and faced a problem. Please take a look at a the following example. This is part of a Node class:

```
private Map<String, Node> nodes;

public Optional<Node> child(String name) {
    return Optional.<Node>ofNullable(nodes.get(name));
}

private void findChildren(String name, List<Node> result) {
    child(name).ifPresent(result::add);
    nodes.values().stream()
//          .map(Node::findChildren(name, result))
//          .forEach(Node::findChildren(name, result))
            .forEach(node -> node.findChildren(name, result));
}
```

My intent was to call #findChildren with the name and result parameters on each node in the stream. I tried to use the method references Node::findChildren with no luck. I'd appreciate solutions other the the one with `->` operator.

Is it somehow possible to use the method reference together with a parameter? I like the idea of streams and I just want to make the code more readable.

Actually, I think there is a similar question [Method references with a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468711/method-references-with-a-parameter) which I read but cannot figure out how to use the bind2 method in my code. Is it the only solution?

Comment: You can only pass metod references where functional interfaces with similar signature required (I.e. it is possible to infer arguments to the lambda)

Comment: forEach() expects a single Node argument and returns void, so only reference to static method accepting single Node, or no-arg method of Node class with void return can be passed there. Solution: create such method by your own.

Comment: https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/method-references-in-java-8 are some good examples for people looking into method references with arguments.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can’t use method references for this purpose. You have to resort to lambda expressions. The reason why the `bind2` method of the linked question doesn’t work is that you are actually trying to bind *two* parameters to convert a three-arg function into a one-arg function. There is no similarly simple solution as there is no standard functional `interface` for three-arg consumers.

It would have to look like

```
interface ThreeConsumer<T, U, V> {
    void accept(T t, U u, V v);
}
public static <T, U, V> Consumer<T> bind2and3(
                        ThreeConsumer<? super T, U, V> c, U arg2, V arg3) {
    return (arg1) -> c.accept(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
```

Then `.forEach(bind2and3(Node::findChildren, name, result));` could work. But is this really simpler than `.forEach(node -> node.findChildren(name, result));`?

Comment: Thank you! How is the `Node::findChildren` with 2 parameters converter to a ThreeConsumer which accepts 3 parameters?

Comment: For non-`static` methods, you have to count the method receiver as a parameter. In your specific case, the consumer is invoked with a `Node` instance as parameter, on which the `findChildren` method will be invoked. Well, this applies if you use `ClassName::methodName` to refer to an instance method. Instead, you could bind a method reference to a particular receiver by saying `object::methodName`, then the method will be invoked on `object`. This happens, e.g. when you say `System.out::println`, where the method `println` will be invoked on the `PrintStream` instance found in `System.out`.

Comment: But in your case, you want process a stream of different `Node` instances so leaving the receiver unbound and counting it as a parameter is what you want. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29803257/2711488)

Comment: Yet another brain-melting hour just to find out that "You can't."