# Call constructor with arguments in a lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

I have Employee class:

```
public class Employee {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String externalId;

    public Employee(Long id, String name, String externalId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.externalId = externalId;
    }

    //getters, setter
}
```

And employee service which returns an employee (NULL is possible).

```
private void performEmployeeProcessing() {
    Long employeeId = 2L;
    Object o = Optional.ofNullable(employeeService.getById(employeeId))
        .orElseGet(Employee::new, 1L, "", "");

    System.out.println(o);
}
```

It says compilation error

> Employee::new, 1L, "", ""
>   Cannot resolve constructor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835382/use-method-reference-with-parameter or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251629/java-8-supplier-with-arguments-in-the-constructor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `Supplier`:

```
.orElseGet(() -> new Employee( 1L, "", ""));
```

FYI, an `Employee` instance will only be created when it's actually needed.

---

If your constructor had no args, you could have used a method reference `Employee::new`. You could still use a method reference if you create a factory method:

```
class Employee {
    // rest of class
    public static Employee createDummy() {
        return new Employee( 1L, "", "");
    }
}
```

then you could:

```
.orElseGet(Employee::createDummy);
```

The factory method could actually be in any class as you like.

Comment: The factory method is a static one, right?

Comment: @Jan it doesn't have to be, but if it's not you need an instance of a factory, which you can still use a method reference with: `class Factory { Employee createDumy() {...}}` then `Factory f = new Factory();` (which can be an instance variable or whatever) and `.orElseGet(f::createDummy)`. I think static factory methods are simpler to use and code because you don't need an instance. But there are times when you want to pass a factory to some code that needs a way to create an instance provided to it. For example, your method could accept such a supplier as an argument