# How to pass argument to class constructor when initialzed thru ::new in Java8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am using java 8 stream API to perform action on a list of `Store` objects.

`Store` takes a `String` argument and a `Mapper` object. `Mapper` will be same for all `Store` object.

Question: How can I pass `Mapper` object when I initialize `Store` here `.map(Store::new)`?

```
public class Store {
    public Store(String name, Mapper mapper) {
    }
}

public class Mapper {
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

        Mapper mapper = new Mapper();
         // compile time problem at Store::new because it takes 2 arguments
         List<Store> actions = 
             names.stream()
              .map(Store::new)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: The following might come in handy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468711/method-references-with-a-parameter

Another solution would be to use lambda expressions instead of static method references.

Comment: To be honest if the mapper is always the same as presented, use a second constructor taking only the String and creating the mapper calling the other constructor: `public Store(String name) { this(name, new Mapper()); }`

Answer (score 15):

You can't use a method reference for a constructor that needs to receive a free variable, i.e. a variable from the context.

Please refer to the [Java Tutorial, section Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to find more info about method references.

You can use a lambda expression instead:

```
Mapper mapper = new Mapper();

List<Store> actions = 
    names.stream()
        .map(name -> new Store(name, mapper))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If, for whatever reason, you insist on using a method reference, you still can, **though the solution is more complex and cumbersome**. In fact, it's much better from all possible points of view to use a lambda expression instead of the hack I'm introducing below. I'm writing it just to show that method references are good only if you already have a method or constructor whose signature matches the expected one.

Suppose you declare this helper method:

```
public static <T, U, R> Function<T, R> bindSecond(
        BiFunction<T, U, R> biFunction, 
        U free) {
    return t -> biFunction.apply(t, free);
}
```

Here I'm are creating and returning a 1-argument function that applies its only one argument to the given bifunction (a 2-argument function), as well as the given free variable. In other words, I'm *binding* the given free variable to the given bifunction as its second argument.

In your example, `Store::new` is actually a bifunction that takes two arguments (`name` and `mapper`) and returns a value (the new `Store` instance), and you are getting that compilation error because `Stream.map` expects a 1-argument function that takes the element of the stream as its only one parameter.

The `bindSecond` helper method actually transforms the given bifunction and free variable into a 1-argument function that matches the signature of the `Stream.map` method.

You could use it as follows:

```
Mapper mapper = new Mapper();

List<Store> actions = 
    names.stream()
        .map(bindSecond(Store::new, mapper))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But again, **I see no point in using this over a simple lambda expression**.

Answer (score 6):

Use a lambda expression instead of a method reference

```
  .map(name -> new Store(name, mapper))
```

Comment: You should remove the question mark, as you posted an answer, not a comment…

Answer (score 0):

**Using Stream generator**

```html
Stream.generate(Item::new)
                .map(item -> new Item("Hello", "Hi"))
                .limit(10)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```